# What is the effect of Rapid Fire attachment on Single Fire Weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Playing modern warfare 3 multi-player, I recently levelled my MK14 up high enough to enable the `Rapid Fire` attachment. The MK14 Assault Rifle is a Semi-automatic (single fire) weapon. As the desciption of `Rapid Fire` states `Increased Fire Rate`, I assumed, using the `Rapid Fire` attachment would turn my semi-automatic (single-fire) into an automatic.

But it seems to have no effect at all. It still is only a single fire weapon.

What is the effect of the `Rapid Fire` attachment on a Semi-Automatic (single-fire) weapon, such as the MK14, if it has one at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/MK14):

> Rapid Fire has a unique effect on the MK14; because the weapon is semi-automatic, Rapid Fire simply raises the fire rate cap, allowing for marginally a faster fire rate. This can be useful in close quarters and when facing many enemies that need to be quickly dispatched; however, for most situations, it's not necessary.

The weapon's stat table on the same page gives:

> Rate of Fire
>
> 545 RPM Max
>
> 681 RPM with Rapid Fire

Basically, it lets the weapon fire faster - if you can pull the trigger fast enough.

Comment: I didn't think anyone was able to answer this, so I posted an answer myself after eventually stumbling across the info. You must have posted while I was writing. I will accept your answer as it is correct :) I still leave my answer there too seeing I spent all that time in the end researching and testing it. Thank you very much your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the wiki. I never even realised there was one. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the MK14, like any other semi-automatic weapon has a fire-cap. This means is has a limit in how fast it can actually shoot, regardless how fast you pull the trigger.

I tested this now and these are the results.

**Without Rapid Fire**
Clicking my mouse in high-speed to shoot it only shot every second/third click.
Basically, regardless how fast I clicked there is a limit in how fast it can actually shoot.

**With Rapid Fire**
Clicking my mouse in high-speed to shoot it shot every click.
When I tried really hard I actually manage at some stage to hit the *new* limit

**Summary**
I know every person clicks their mouse in different speeds and mine may not be as fast or as slow as yours.

The bottom line is that that semi-automatic weapons have a **firing-cap** that in the case of the MK14 seems approximately 2-3 shots a second **without** `Rapid Fire` and 
at least double that **with** `Rapid Fire`.

The default **firing-cap**, may or may not vary between different semi-automatic weapons but I have not tested that.

Attaching `Rapid Fire` increases that cap by about 100%.

**Conclusion**
If you are trigger happy and you are able to click that mouse with ease so fast that you find your semi-automatic is not able to keep up with you then `Rapid Fire` is going to help you out.

If you are like me were it rarely happens then `Rapid Fire` is not as much of a benefit to you.